# scrape dynamic chart data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://shipandbunker.com/prices/emea/nwe/nl-rtm-rotterdam#_IFO380

I want to scrape the price of Rotterdam-IFO380 on 07/04/2019( $380.50) in the dynamic chart from above website.

I am not sure if beautifulsoup is the best way to do it if I want to store the data to my local db.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pymongo

# URL of page to be scraped
url = 'https://shipandbunker.com/prices/emea/nwe/nl-rtm-rotterdam#IFO380'

# Retrieve page with the requests module
response = requests.get(url)

# Create BeautifulSoup object; parse with 'lxml'
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: page uses JavaScript to display data but BS doesn't run JavaScript. You may have to use Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript. Or use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to find url used by JavaScript to get data and use it  with `requests.get()`. Usually JavaScript reads data in JSON which can be easily converted to Python's dictionary and you don't have to scrape HTML. You could also check if page doesn't have API to give easy access to data.

Comment: using DevTools I see it makes POST requests (with some arguments) to `https://shipandbunker.com/a/.json` to get some data in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses JavaScript to get all data and create graph.

JavaScript uses `POST` request with url https://shipandbunker.com/a/.json to get data in JSON format which can be easily converted to Python's dictionary and it doesn't need BeautifulSoup to scrape HTML.

```
import requests
import datetime

day = datetime.date(2019, 7, 4)

payload = {
    'api-method': 'pricesForAllSeriesGet',
    'resource': 'MarketPriceGraph_Block',
    'mc0': 'NL RTM',
    'mc1': 'AV G20',
}

url = 'https://shipandbunker.com/a/.json'
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
#print(r.content)

data = r.json()

for number, value in data['api']['NL RTM']['data']['prices']['IFO380']['dayprice']:

    # convert day number to date object
    timestamp = data['api']['NL RTM']['data']['day_list']['IFO380'][str(number)]
    date = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(timestamp/1000)

    if date == day:
        print(day, value)
        break
```

It displays

```
2019-07-04 380.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! can i change the if statement as below                             if date > 2019-07-03 19:00:00:
        print(date, value)

Comment: you can't use directly `2019-07-03 19:00:00`. You would have to conver it to `datetime.datetime` object similar to my current code `day = datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 3, 19, 00, 00)` and `date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp/1000)` and then `if date > day`. Or use only date `datetime.date(2019, 7, 3)` without hour and then `if date > day` should also work.

Comment: if you want all data which date is > 2019-07-03 19:00:00 then you have to also remove `break`

Comment: Could you share the steps you go through to find the api? how do you know to use this url: https://shipandbunker.com/a/.json

Comment: Chrome/Firefox has built-in DevTool (somewhere in menu: `"Tools for web developers"` or shortcut `F12`) which opens few tabs in bottom of the window. One of the tab is `"Network"` which shows all requests send from browser to server and responses from server. You can filter it to see only `XHR` (AJAX) request. And then It shows few requests to https://shipandbunker.com/a/.json. If you click on request (in left part) then it show details in right part - there are information about headers, cookies, parameteres used in requests. I put parameters as `payload` in code.

Comment: I want to use datetime.astimezone() to convert my result 2019-07-03 380.5 to the output you had( my local time is U.S time and i think the chart uses European time which caused different output running the same code) Can i add .astimezone() after .fromtimestamp?

Answer (score 2):

You can scrape every site that you want with `Scrapy`

here is a simple spider to scrape:

> URL : https://shipandbunker.com/prices/emea/nwe/nl-rtm-rotterdam#_IFO380

#### spiders.py

```py
import scrapy


class ShippingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shipping_spider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://shipandbunker.com/prices/emea/nwe/nl-rtm-rotterdam#_IFO380',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        xpath = '//*[@id="block_284"]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/text()'
        rotterdam = response.xpath(xpath).extract()
        print(rotterdam)

        # output: ['315.00']
```

It's really easy to set up and manage spiders, here is the [Doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to search for a specific date within the json returned dynamically from the API call you can find in the network tab. Slightly different implementation from the other answer.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, date
import calendar

def get_timestamp(date_var):
    return calendar.timegm(date_var.timetuple()) * 1000

data = [
  ('api-method', 'pricesForAllSeriesGet'),
  ('resource', 'MarketPriceGraph_Block'),
  ('mc0', 'NL RTM'),
  ('mc1', 'AV G20')]

r = requests.post('https://shipandbunker.com/a/.json', data=data).json()
date_var = get_timestamp(date(2019, 7, 4))
d = r['api']['NL RTM']['data']['day_list']['IFO380']
keys = list(d.keys())
prices = r['api']['NL RTM']['data']['prices']['IFO380']['dayprice']
found = [i for i in range(len(d.keys())) if d[keys[i]] == date_var][0]
print(prices[found][1])
```